# Use R to validate Central Limit Theorem

Tags: r, time-series, normal-distribution, simulation

everyone. I am learning Time Series analysis. I am wondering if I can use R program  to validate central limit theorem.

Consider an AR(1) data generating process:
$$Y_t=\varphi_*Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$
where $\epsilon_t \sim i.i.d. N(0 ,{\sigma ^2})$ and $\varphi_*=0.5$

Using OLS method to estimate the following model:
$$Y_t=\beta_*Y_{t-1}+U_t$$
When sample size $n \rightarrow \infty,\hat{\beta_n}\rightarrow\beta_*=\varphi_*=0.5$, and $U_t=\epsilon_t$

By central limit theorem, when sample size $n \rightarrow \infty $,we have

$$\begin{align*}
 \sqrt n(\hat{\beta_n}-\beta_*)&=(\frac{1}{n}\sum{Y_{t-1}^2})^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum{Y_{t-1}U_t} \\
 &\rightarrow E(Y_{t-1}^2)^{-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum{Y_{t-1}U_t}\\
&\thicksim N(0,E(Y_{t-1}^2)^{-1}E(U_t^2Y_{t-1}^2)E(Y_{t-1}^2)^{-1})\\
&\thicksim N(0,E(Y_{t-1}^2)^{-1}E(\epsilon_t^2Y_{t-1}^2)E(Y_{t-1}^2)^{-1})\\
&\thicksim N(0,\sigma^2E(Y_{t-1}^2)^{-1})\\
&\thicksim N(0,1-\varphi_*^2)
\end{align*}$$
So my question boils down to how to use R to generate a AR(1) process with parameter $\varphi=0.5$ estimate it by OLS, construct a sequence of $\sqrt n(\hat{\beta_n}-0.5)$ and measure whether it follows normal distribution with mean 0 and covariance 0.75.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: @gung You cannot prove the central limit theorem just by example in R or any other software code/program.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, that's true. I'm assuming he wants to illustrate how it works / be able to explore the topic. As you know, in statistical research people often have proofs & then simulations. I'm thinking that's what he has in mind, but you are making a valid point that can be cleared up for him.

Comment: @gung That sounds reasonable.  That you for the suggestion.